# Python: request module confirm popup

Tags: python, request

After POST request, there is confirmation(jquery) box appears in browser.

So How do I select confirmation box using request api ?

Here HTML page :

```
<div class="sent_sms_bg">
    <form name="smsAction" id="smsAction" action="/sms_all_action" method="post">
    <p><input name="" id="select_all" type="checkbox" value="" /> Select All</p>
    <p><input name="Delete_SMS" type="button" class="delete_selected" value="Delete Selected" />
    </p>
</div>
```

and What I'm trying :

```
self.session = requests.session()

..
...
url = 'http://www.indyarocks.com/sms_all_action'

form = {
    'select_all' : 'on',
    'Delete_SMS': 'Delete Selected',
    }

status = self.session.post(url , data = form)
```

Answer (score 0):

POSTing directly to the url should work, as presumably the website has a form with an ajax popup to make sure you *really* want to submit the form, THEN POSTs the data to the URL. It wouldn't work to POST the data first and then fire the popup (as the form is already submitted so it's too late to do anything about it)